# What open source protocol does android sdk follow

Tags: android

is adnroid sdk open source ?  here i found the code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/    if it's open source ,What open source protocol does  android sdk  follow ? Apache Licence 2.0 ?   thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several licenses used in the Android Open Source Platform, with Apache 2.0 being the preferred one. [More information](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/about/licenses).